# Pandas to_csv method's option quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL is NOT working

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Pandas `DataFrame.to_csv` method's option `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` seems not working.

I have following input tab delimited data, In the following example -> denotes tab and . denotes space chars.

`Jhon->35->123.Vroom.St->01120`

After using `DataFrame.to_csv` and option quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` I am expecting following output.

`Jhon 35 "123 Vroom St" 01120`

Which means quote only address values where there is space in the delimited data and do not quote if no space.

```
df.to_csv(file,
          sep='\t',
          header=False,
          index=False,
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

However, I am getting following output. There is no quote on the address.

`Jhon 35 123 Vroom St 01120`

Using option quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` getting me below which I don't want.

`"Jhon" "35" "123 Vroom St" "01120"`

Could someone please help me what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Well... minimal means don't quote unless you need to... since "123 Vroom St" doesn't contain tabs... it doesn't need escaping... - if you were to specify your delimiter as a space you'd find it would be quoted

Comment: Thanks Jon. I changed the delimiter to space and getting the quotes around address but lost the tabs, they are now showing as spaces.
Jhon\s35\s"123 Vroom St"\s01120

Comment: I need like =>   Jhon\t35\t"123 Vroom St"\t01120

Comment: You can't have both... CSV is literally just a character stream with defined delimiters and escaping where needed. I guess the question is - why is the default output not what you want?

Comment: Yes... but why do you *need* that? That's the question. (It's completely valid that any even half decent system can read back later)

Comment: I have written an old perl app in python which processes client data files. now I have to compare output files from both the systems and mark it passed. however because of this quoting issue files are different. The old system's output is Jhon\t35\t"123 Vroom St"\t01120 and I want same output for the new system. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Following options are available in Pandas for quotes:

1. csv.QUOTE_ALL: quote all fields
2. csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL: quote those fields which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any of the characters in lineterminator.
3. csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC :quote all non-numeric fields.
4. csv.QUOTE_NONE : never quote fields.

In your case, as you are using csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL and your text does not any special characters mentioned above, none of the field will be quoted. I will suggest using csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC to get the format you are looking for.

```
df.to_csv(file, sep='\t', header=False, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You could patch the column before writing the csv

```
df["foo"] = '"' + df["foo"] + '"'
df.to_csv(file, sep='\t', header=False, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```